# что значит I в ER - диаграмме

Tags: sql, база-данных

Что значат I1, I2, I3  и I4  в ER-диаграмме? C PK и FK вопросов нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Думаю что индексы.

Comment: @Духсообщества я реконструировал схему базы данных из acceess в visio и у меня возник вопрос, что значат эти обозначения.

Comment: @Alpensin индексы чего?на что они указывают, какую информацию они дают?

Comment: @Vs_De_S Хотя тогда и для PK было бы по идее. Поля, на которые создаются внешние ключи как правило индексированы.  Для многих СУБД полагаю индексация необходимое условие для создания ключа.  Индексирование используется для быстрого поиска по соответствующему полю.